# What does the term "reason about" mean in computer science?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming

While learning functional programming, I keep coming across the term "reason about" especially in the context of pure functions and/or referential transparency. Can somebody explain what exactly does this mean?

Comment: The expression “reason about programs” refers to tools that could exist for functional programming languages, allowing to mathematically prove their behavior with respect to a formally expressed specification. These tools would be similar to KeY for Java or Frama-C for the C language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KeY http://frama-c.com

Comment: "Reason about" in CS means exactly the same as "reason about" in any other field or context.

Comment: You might also want to learn about the Halting Problem and how it was proven undecidable.  This puts a hard limit on our ability to reason about programs in Turing-complete languages.

Comment: *reason about* in Reat: *which props are being passed in which makes your apps easy to **reason about***. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: The "reasoning" is "about" the "program" *doing what it's supposed to*. (It is a computer science & software engineering term that arose in the 60s.) (The hard reasoning is re conditionals and invariants (recursion, looping & concurrency).

Answer (score 53):

Typically when writing a program, your job doesn't end with merely writing the code, but you would also want to know some properties your code exhibits. You can arrive at these properties by two means: either by logical analysis or by empirical observation.

Examples of such properties include:

- correctness (does the program do what it is supposed to)
- performance (how long does it take)
- scalability (how is performance affected with input)
- security (can the algorithm be maliciously misused)

When you measure these properties empirically, you get results with limited precision. Therefore mathematically proving these properties is far superior, however it is not always easy to do. Functional languages typically have as one of their design goals making mathematical proofs of their properties more tractable. This is what is typically meant by reasoning about programs.

---

In terms of functions or lesser units, the above applies, but also sometimes the author simply means thinking about the algorithm or designing the algorithm. It depends on the particular usage.

---

As an aside, some examples of how one might reason about some of these things and how empirical observation can be made:

*Correctness:* We can prove that code is correct, if we can show equationally that it does what it is supposed to do. So for a sort function if we can show that any list we give it will have the property of being sorted, we know our code is correct. Empirically we can create a unit test suite where we give our code examples of input and check that the code has the desired output.

*Performance & Scalability:* We can analyze our code and prove performance bounds of the algorithm so that we know how does the time it takes depend on the size of the input. Empirically we can benchmark our code and see how quickly it actually runs on a particular machine. We can perform load testing and seeing how much actual input can our machine/algorithm take before it folds/becomes impractical.

Comment: For the four categories, empiricism means: 1. let QA find the bug. 2. let your friendly users complain. 3. let your IT guy call you at 3 am after a server crash. 4. donate your data and servers to your unfriendly users. Any of these methods means your job ends with writing the code. In this context, your boss will say, "Lemme tell you the reason about why I'm firing you." He may spit unintentionally as he says it.

Answer (score 34):

Reasoning about code, in *the most loose sense of the word*, means thinking about your code and what it *really* does (not what you think it should do.) It means

- being aware of **the way your code behaves** when you throw data at it,
- knowing **what things you can refactor without breaking it**, and
- keeping tabs on **what optimisations can be performed**,

among other things. For me, the reasoning part plays the biggest role when I'm debugging or refactoring.

To use an example you mentioned: Referential transparency helps me a lot when I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with a function. The referential transparency guarantees that as I'm poking around with the function, giving it different arguments, I know that the function will react the same way inside my program. It doesn't depend on anything other than its arguments. That makes the function easier to reason about – as opposed to an imperative language where the function may depend on some external variable that can change under my nose.

Another way of looking at it (and this is more helpful when refactoring) is that the more you know your code satisfies certain properties, the easier it becomes to reason about. I know, for example, that

```
map f (map g xs) === map (f . g) xs
```

This is a useful property I can just apply directly when I'm refactoring. The fact that I can state such properties of Haskell code makes it easier to reason about. I could try to state this property in a Python program, but I would be much, much less confident of it, because if I'm unlucky in my choices of `f` and `g` the results may vary wildly.

Answer (score 19):

Informally it means, "Being able to tell what a program will do just by looking at the code."  This can be surprisingly difficult in most languages, due to side-effects, casting, implicit conversions, overloaded functions and operators, etc.  I.e., when you can't reason about code using just your brain, you have to run it to see what it will do for a given input.

Answer (score 12):

Usually when people say "reasoning" they mean "equational reasoning", which means proving properties about your code without ever running it.

These properties can be very simple.  For example, given the following definition of `(.)` and `id`:

```
id :: a -> a
id x = x

(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
(f . g) = \x -> f (g x)
```

... we might then want to prove that:

```
f . id = f
```

This is easy to prove because:

```
(f . id) = \x -> f (id x) = \x -> f x = f
```

Notice how I've proven this for **all** `f`.  This means that I know that this property is always true no matter what, therefore I no longer need to test this property in some sort of unit test suite because I know that it can never fail.

Comment: The *hard* reasoning "proving properties about your code" is re implication--invariants (recursion, looping & concurrency) and conditionals.

Answer (score 10):

"Reasoning about a program" is just "analyzing a program to see what it does".

The idea is that purity simplifies understanding, both by a human changing a program and by a machine compiling a program or analyzing it for broken corner cases.

Answer (score 3):

Many correct answers to this question have already been given, referring to mathematical proofs of correctness. But I hope to provide a practical answer for programmers who aren't necessarily maths majors.

As Douglas Crockford observed, formal proofs of correctness do not feature very heavily in contemporary programming practice.[1]

The phrase "reason about your code" first made practical sense to me during the debugging phase. The question is: ***When things go wrong, how easy is it for you to determine why they went wrong?***

If each function's behaviour depends only on its inputs, then it should be fairly trivial to predict what can happen inside the function body. An unanticipated error means that some input case wasn't handled. (For example, a common problem is not anticipating a `null` argument.)

If, on the other hand, a function's result depends on the state of external variables that the function does not own or control, then it can be very difficult to trace what led to the state that the system was in, when the error occurred. (Resolving these questions is the motivation behind a lot of the logging that systems do.)

This is the reason that the functional style is said to allow you to "reason about" your code.

- It limits what could go wrong to what can happen between a function's parameters, and its return value.
- It constrains what could go wrong to the few elements that the function owns and controls.

And if you know in what function an error was encountered, then you should be able to figure out pretty easily what must have gone wrong, and how it got that way. (And, if necessary, unwind the call stack to the places where unexpected values must have gotten in.)

"Reasoning about" is also demonstrated by the Behaviour-Driven Development paradigm:

**Given:** A limited number of possible initial conditions. (eg, Parameters.)

**When:** The process that you define is executed.

**Then:** There is a limited and known range of possible results.

That is "reasoning about" code, in a nutshell.

(And of course, this also depends on your function body not modifying external variables, which is what functional programmers like to call "side effects".)

[Edsger Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) famously campaigned against the `goto` statement. If a program was allowed to arbitrarily jump to any line in its definition, he reasoned, then you could not hope to predict its runtime behaviour.

The functional programming paradigm takes this even further: It wants to limit the influence of any state that is external to a program's logic to what is strictly necessary in order to achieve its purpose.

This is so that - when you're debugging an error - just reading the code should be enough to understand its cause.

[1]: Crockford, Douglas. "How Testing Works". *How Javascript Works.* Virgule-Solidus LLC, 2018. EPUB.

Answer (score 0):

As @John Wiegley said, reason about means

> being able to tell what a program will do just by looking at the code

What is more important is to understand **what hinders us to reason about our code**. These are **side-effects**.